# How can I use webrtc without any server of my own?

Tags: javascript, network-programming, p2p

Is there a way to use webrtc without any server or cost and without downloading anything? I'm trying to make a peer to peer network without a server of any kind (I can't set up my own). Every tutorial that I've found needs some kind of server, or downloading node.js, or using some service that you pay for with a subscription. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC is actually a Peer to Peer RTC Protocol which happens between browser.

But you got it in wrong way. For establishing the direct link between two systems WebRTC requires,

The topology between itself, and the peer it wants to communicate with

Establish connectivity on the best path through a given topology

Have a fallback mechanism if all else fails.

WebRTC standards require the use of  three IEFT NAT traversal standards to address these issues:

Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE) –  RFC 5245

Session Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN) – RFC 5389

Traversal Using Relay NAT (TURN) – RFC 5766

So, the final answer is it's not possible with WebRTC.

Comment: You can build signalling server with any language. If you are doing this for learning you can spin up a server in your local and use it as signalling. Else if you want it to try in real world try using PHP, cause you can get free hosting supporting this language.